# Symfony 5 проблема с формой отправки данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, relation, symfony5

У меня возникла небольшая проблема, которая заключается в том, чтобы отправить данные резюме в компанию. В базе данных MySQL у меня созданы три таблицы: company, summary и company_summary.

Таблица company:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица summary:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица summary_company:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Между таблицами были настроены следующие связи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Между таблицами company и summary связь много ко многим. То есть компания может иметь много вариантов резюме, а резюме может быть отправлено в N-количество компаний. Чтобы отправлять данные резюме кандидата в компанию я решила создать форму, в которой нужно будет выбрать из селекта вакансию, которая предварительно была раньше создана пользователем и выбрать из селекта нужную компанию.

Модель Company:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CompanyRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CompanyRepository::class)
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $website;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $phone_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Summary", mappedBy="companies")
     */
    private $summaries;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->companies = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWebsite(): ?string
    {
        return $this->website;
    }

    public function setWebsite(?string $website): self
    {
        $this->website = $website;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone_number;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(string $phone_number): self
    {
        $this->phone_number = $phone_number;

        return $this;
    }

    /*
    * @return Collection|Company[]
    */
   public function getCompanies(): Collection
   {
       return $this->companies;
   }

   public function addCompanies(Company $company): self
   {
       if (!$this->companies->contains($company)) {
           $this->companies[] = $company;
           $company->addCompanies($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function removeCompanies(Company $company): self
   {
       if ($this->companies->contains($company)) {
           $this->companies->removeElement($company);
           $company->removeCompanies($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }
    
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Summary:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SummaryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SummaryRepository::class)
 */
class Summary
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $vacancy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1000)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="summaries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $published;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="summaries", cascade={"persist"}))
     */
    private $companies;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->summaries = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getVacancy(): ?string
    {
        return $this->vacancy;
    }

    public function setVacancy(string $vacancy): self
    {
        $this->vacancy = $vacancy;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserId(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function getPublished(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->published;
    }

    public function setPublished(bool $published): self
    {
        $this->published = $published;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Summary[]
     */
    public function getSummaries(): Collection
    {
        return $this->summaries;
    }
    
    public function addSummaries(Summary $summary): self
    {
        if (!$this->summaries->contains($summary)) {
            $this->summaries[] = $summary;
        }
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function removeSummaries(Summary $summary): self
    {
        if ($this->summaries->contains($summary)) {
            $this->summaries->removeElement($summary);
        }
        return $this;
    }
   
   public function __toString()
   {
        return $this->getVacancy();
   }
}
```

SummaryCompany:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SummaryCompanyRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SummaryCompanyRepository::class)
 */
class SummaryCompany
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $receivedAt;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="summary_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $summaryId;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="company_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $companyId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $companyName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $summaryVacancy;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="summaries", cascade={"persist"}))
     */
    private $companies;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Summary", mappedBy="companies")
    */
    private $summaries;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->summaries = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->companies = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->receivedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Company[]|null
     */
    public function getCompanies(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->companies;
    }

    public function setCompanies(Company $companies): self
    {
        $this->companies = $companies;

        if ($companies->getSummary() !== $this) {
            $companies->setSummary($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Summary[]|null
     */
    public function getSummaries(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->summaries;
    }

    public function setSummaries(Summary $summaries): self
    {
        $this->summaries = $summaries;

        if ($summaries->getCompany() !== $this) {
            $summaries->setCompany($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
   
    
    public function getCompanyName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->companyName;
    }

    public function setCompanyName(string $companyName): self
    {
        $this->companyName = $companyName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSummaryVacancy(): ?string
    {
        return $this->summaryVacancy;
    }

    public function setSummaryVacancy(string $summaryVacancy): self
    {
        $this->summaryVacancy = $summaryVacancy;

        return $this;
    }
    

    public function getReceivedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->receivedAt;
    }

    public function setReceivedAt(\DateTimeInterface $receivedAt): self
    {
        $this->receivedAt = $receivedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set summaryId
     *
     * @param integer $summaryId
     *
     * @return Summary
     */
    public function setSummaryId($summaryId)
    {
        $this->summaryId = $summaryId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get summaryId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSummaryId()
    {
        return $this->summaryId;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyId
     *
     * @param integer $companyId
     *
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setCompanyId($companyId)
    {
        $this->companyId = $companyId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCompanyId()
    {
        return $this->companyId;
    }
}
```

SummaryController:

```
  /**
     * @Route("/send_summary", name="send_summary", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * @param Request $request 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function send_summary(Request $request): Response
    {
        $summaryCompany = new SummaryCompany();
        //dd($summaryCompany);
        $summaries = new Summary();
        $companies = new Company();

        $summaries->addSummaries($summaryCompany);
        $summaries->setId($this->getVacancy());
        $companies->addCompanies($summaryCompany);
        $companies->setId($this->geName());    

        $form = $this->createForm(SummaryCompanyType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $entityManager= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
            $entityManager->persist($summaryCompany); 
            //dd($summaryCompany);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Резюме успішно відправлено!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('summary.index');
        }
        
        return $this->render('summary/send_summary.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

SummaryCompanyType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\SummaryCompany;
use App\Entity\Company;
use App\Entity\Summary;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;

class SummaryCompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('summaries', EntityType::class, array( 
                'class' => Summary::class, 
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_value' => function (Summary $summary = null) {
                    return null === $summary ? '': $summary->getVacancy();
                },
            ))
            ->add('companies', EntityType::class, array( 
                'class' => Company::class, 
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_value' => function (Company $company = null) {
                    return null === $company ? '': $company->getName();
                },
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SummaryCompany::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

_receive_form.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.summaries, {
        label: 'Посада'
    }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.companies, {
        label: 'Компанії'
    }) }}
    <button class="btn btn-success"><i class='fas fa-plus-square'></i> Зберегти</button>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path('summary.index') }}"><i class='fas fa-briefcase'></i> Список резюме</a>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Вот так выглядит форма отправки резюме в компанию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе на страницу формы возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень много времени прошло, и я думая, что проблема в контроллере, и есть неточности в моделях. Помогите найти ошибки и исправить. Все коды моделей и контроллера приведены выше.

Comment: А __конкретная проблема__ тут в чем? "там чего-то не хватает" - как ты поняла что чего-то не хватает?

Comment: пока разбираюсь с этим

Comment: очевидно, что у вас доктринячья коллекция, которая ассоциирует отношение ко многим где-то пытается сконвертиться в инт. По приведенным кусочкам непонятно... Возможно стоит привести побольше данных исключения

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле ошибка очень конкретно все объясняет, нужно только вдумчиво прочитать.

Для метода addSummaries() ожидается Summary, а передан SummaryCompany, в строке 88 SummaryController

Ваш код:

```
...
public function send_summary(Request $request): Response
{
    $summaryCompany = new SummaryCompany();
    //dd($summaryCompany);
    $summaries = new Summary();
    $companies = new Company();

    $summaries->addSummaries($summaryCompany);
    $summaries->setId($this->getVacancy());
...
```

А нужно:

```
...
public function send_summary(Request $request): Response
{
    $summaryCompany = new SummaryCompany();
    //dd($summaryCompany);
    $summaries = new Summary();
    $companies = new Company();

    $summaries->addSummaries($summaries);
    $summaries->setId($this->getVacancy());
...
```

Это по логике.
Только далее Вас будет ожидать разочарование в виде ошибки (той же самой) со строкой

```
$companies->addCompanies($summaryCompany);
```

Это что касается данной ошибки.
***Но!*** В действительности Вам эти строки **вообще не нужны**

```
$summaries = new Summary();
$companies = new Company();

$summaries->addSummaries($summaryCompany);
$summaries->setId($this->getVacancy());
$companies->addCompanies($summaryCompany);
$companies->setId($this->geName());
```

Так как symfony строит Вашу форму из Вашего SummaryCompanyType, где уже прописаны поля формы с заполненными данными, то

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

получит выбранные данные из формы, а

```
$entityManager->persist($summaryCompany);
$entityManager->flush();
```

запишут отправленные данные в базу